# Excel Summary Sheet based upon a Value from separate worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a Summary Sheet, whereby a look is carried out on one cell say A1 from the Summary Sheet - called Location.  I'm then wanting a value in the next cell say A2, to be either L, P or N depending upon the result of the look on two separate worksheets.

If the Location Value on the Live Worksheet is True, and the Planned Worksheet is False, I want the value on the Summary Sheet to be L
If the Location Value on the Live Worksheet is Planned, and the Planned Worksheet is True, I want the value on the Summary Sheet to be P

If the Location Value on both the Live Worksheet and Planned Worksheet is False, I want the value on the Summary Sheet to be N

Does anyone know of a way this could be carried out, as I'm so far banging my head on a wall.

Comment: Probably some nested `if` statements?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add some example screenshots of your sheets, your expected results  and the formula you tried so far in order to make it easier for others to reproduce what you are asking.